# Can't execute ping from program

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork, ping

I'm trying to execute `ping` command within my program. I'm working on newest Raspian on RaspBerry Pi B Model. It tells me that: 

`/bin/sh-c: 0: Can't open ping -c 1 192.168.0.12`

My code(it's not finished jet, i know that following code can have some issues):

```
int status;
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
const char* commandChar = commandName.c_str();
if(pid == 0)
{
    execl(SHELL, SHELL "-c", commandChar, NULL);
    _exit(1);
}else if(pid < 0)
{
    return false;
}
commandChar = NULL;
    delete commandChar;
return true;
```

`Ping (/bin/ping)` have `rwsr-xr-x` permissions, so why I can't execute it and how to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using popen() instead?

Comment: I tried to use popen(), but i'm getting whole output of `ping` command. I just want exit code, so I will know that ping is successful.

Comment: Just parse the output for the exit code and you'll be good to go. : )

Comment: But there is a lot of output to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execl expects a file path, you are giving it the file path "/bin/ping -c 192.168.0.12", which of course doesn't exist. Look at the [man page for execl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl), you will see that the last argument is used for the arguments to the program to be run.

Comment: @Over Killer, you'll want to `wait` on that child somewhere, especially if you plan on executing ping multiple times.

Comment: Probably, but he didn't ask about that :P

Comment: I know.  It wasn't required of the answer, I just get a little OCD about things now and again.

Comment: @Duck Thanks for advice. But how long should `wait` be? How do i know how long should program wait?

Comment: @Over Killer, basic choices: (1) `wait` will block the parent until the child dies; (2) you can poll for dead children periodically with `waitpid` and NOHANG option; (3) set up signal handler for SIGCHLD and  (asynchronously) reap the child with waitpid in the handler when it dies.